# vue.js multiple select error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

problem with vue.js multiple select  i tried  many solution but i didn't find the solution
and i get error [Vue warn]:  expects an Array value for its binding, but got String

```
     <select name="users_id[]" multiple class="form-control" v-model="model.users_id" >
         <option>Select</option>
         <option v-for="users in option.users"
         v-bind:value="users.id">
         {{users.name}}
        </option>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        </select>
 <script>   
    export default {
            props: ['title'],
            data(){
                return {
                   model: {
                        'title': '',
                        'users_id': '',
                    },
                    option: {
                        users: []
                    },
                }
            },
            created(){
                this.fetchData();
            },
            methods: {
                fetchData() {
                    let vm = this;
                    axios.get('/subject/create')
                        .then(function(response) {
                            Vue.set(vm.$data, 'option',   response.data.option)
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            console.log(error)
                        })
                },
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One problem : `multiple v-model="model.users_id"` and `users_id': ''` :

You have a `v-model` with `multiple options` so the variable link with `v-model` must be an Array. But You passed a String with `users_id': ''`.

So do :

```
model: {
  'title': '',
  'users_id': [],
},
```

Comment: What if you are generating the name of the link on the fly like: `v-model="search[name_of_field]`?

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
model: {
  'title': '',
  'users_id': '',
},
```

To:

```
model: {
  'title': '',
  'users_id': []
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
Vue.set(vm.$data, 'option',   response.data.option)
```

you are setting the `option` property, which should be an object containing an Array named `users`. The value you are setting it to is (probably) a JSON-encoded form of that, which is to say, a string.

This might fix it:

```
Vue.set(vm.$data, 'option', JSON.parse(response.data.option))
```